# 'name' attribute should be defined - error in android manifest

Tags: android

In my android project manifest, Android Studio gives an inspection error in a `android:uses-permission` element. But app successfully compiles.

[image]

[image]
What is the meaning of this inspection? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can see the error based on first three lines. Delete **android:** part from line. Write:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

instead of:

```
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine how this happened!  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Brandon, it probably happened due to a bug like this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=136079 If you'd like to vote for that bug to be fixed, you can "star" it.

Comment: This bug has resurfaced in the latest update of Android Studio. I created a Navigation Drawer Activity and manifest added the same unnecessary permissions with the ill-constructed signature.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This also works

Comment: Looks like a recent android update destroyed our code, but this is the way to go - change description into name.